# PyCharm doesn't recognize imports for py files in the same directory with python3.7 interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a new project I'm working on, which started with python2.7 interpreter. Here's the directory tree:

```
/work/
|- app/
|- __init__.py
|-- tools/
|--- logger.py
|--- utils.py
```

Inside `utils.py` I have an import statement to `logger.py`. They both located on the same directory.

With the current interpreter of my PyCharm IDE `Local Python /usr/local/bin/python2.7` it works.. but when I change it to the new interpreter I installed using `brew` - `Python 3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7` the IDE fails to recognize *simple import statements of py files within the same directory*.

- I have tried to switch between the interpreters, it resolves everytime I switch to the python2.7
- I tried *Invalidate Caches* from the File menu, it didn't help.
- I overlooked the pycharm settings, looking for a clue.. but couldn't find any
- I'm using PyCharm 2018.1, with the latest update.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: There's no trace, because I'm not running the script. The IDE complains on failed imports, hence it doesn't recongnize the package / classes / methods in it.

Comment: @PMende thanks a lot. Shame I didn't find it myself. Thank you

Comment: No worries. Glad that resolved the issue.